# Removing tab spaces in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
INNER JOIN view AS vw ON vw.[Id] = vw2.[Id]
```

The problem is the return in vw2.[Id] contains a tab space at the end ('2012    ') and vw does not ('2012'). So I tried doing

```
INNER JOIN view AS vw ON vw.[Id] = Replace(vw2.[Id], char(9), '')
```

Unfortunately, the comparison still returns false. I thought that it cannot be done on joins so I tried it on a select query

```
SELECT * 
FROM database.view2 
WHERE REPLACE(Id, char(9), '') = '2012  '
```

But this query also returns a false. Can someone explain to me what concept am I missing or misunderstanding?

EDIT

Hello and thank you to everyone who took their time to help me on this. It seems that

```
vw.[Id] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(vw2.[Id], char(9), '')
```

did the trick. I keep on using `REPLACE` on both ends which resulted from a very long query time which is not necessary. I used `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` also to get the data but from the return of `varbinary` it should not be needed and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. But it works now thank you everyone.

Comment: What data types are the two Id's stored as?

Comment: Hi @Sturgus both are in nvarchar

Comment: what is the result of  `select vw2.[Id], cast(vw2.[Id] as varbinary(max))` for a value that you believe ends in a single tab?

Comment: Hello @Alex K. I don't know what this is but the return of cast(vw2.[id] as varbinary(max)) is 

0x4F00500045002D0030003000300035003400390033003200360038000900

Comment: It shows the characters in the string - as you say there is a single tab on the end (0x09) preceeded by 0x38 ("8") so replace should work, `if replace(cast(0x4F00500045002D0030003000300035003400390033003200360038000900 as nvarchar(max)), char(9), '') = 'OPE-0005493268' print 1` prints 1

Comment: Great info! Thanks for this! I know replace should do the job and i don't understand why it isn't working.:\

Comment: If none of this stuff is working, then maybe they really aren't equal. Do `cast(Id as varbinary(max))` on both of them, and compare those hex outputs to see if they truly are identical, or if they just appear to be.

Comment: Hello @Joe Enos i believe they are equal without the tab. Below are the varbinary for the 2 Ids i compare

0x4F00500045002D003000300030003500340039003300320036003800
0x4F00500045002D0030003000300035003400390033003200360038000900

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the culprit IDs to not have the tab?  I've never known an ID to have a tab on purpose...

Comment: I agree with you on that one! @Sturgus  I hate that the Id has a tab! But the data comes from the client and I cannot do anything about that. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there may be more characters you're dealing with than just a tab. For example, you include 
`REPLACE(Id, char(9), '') = '2012 '`
Why is there still a space on the end after the replace?

I was able to get your method to work in SQL 2008R2, so below is proof-of-concept code.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (
Id varchar(5)
)

CREATE TABLE #table2 (
Id varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES
('2012')
,('2013')
,('2014')
,('2015')
,('2016')

INSERT INTO #table2
VALUES
('2012'+CHAR(9))
,('2013'+CHAR(9))
,('2014'+CHAR(9))
,('2015'+CHAR(9))
,('2016'+CHAR(9))

SELECT t1.Id, t2.Id
FROM #table1 t1
INNER JOIN #table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = REPLACE(t2.Id,CHAR(9),'')
```

See if that gives you the proper results - it does for me.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. But have you tried inserting "tab" in the string instead of + CHAR(9)? If that works also, maybe it's because i'm using nvarchar?

Comment: Less-than-thorough testing char and nchar variants, along with actually using tab inside the string, also shows proper results.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I really appreciate it. Then if that's the case this is frustrating. Should i restart my sql? lol

Comment: SQL Server is probably not the problem. If this test works for you, then it means your logic is correct but your understanding of the field content is not, and narrows (hopefully) your investigation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems right.  Have you tried:

```
INNER JOIN view AS vw ON vw.[Id] = RTRIM(vw2.[Id])
```

?

You could also combine trims and replaces as a way to get rid of all of the whitespace.  Though, it seems like using a sledgehammer to get what you want...

```
INNER JOIN view AS vw ON REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(vw.[Id]), char(9), '') = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(vw2.[Id]), char(9), '')
```

Comment: Already tried this one, didn't work though. I know this should be simple but i don't know why it isn't working :\

Comment: Hm... if the above edit doesn't work, I think you're going to have to inspect your values in both Ids a little more closely.  It should do the job.

Comment: I tried casting it in varbinary(max) to show the difference of the two and this is the result

0x4F00500045002D003000300030003500340039003300320036003800
0x4F00500045002D0030003000300035003400390033003200360038000900

It seems that the tab is the only difference but i don't get why it isn't working

Comment: And the resulting query returns an empty dataset, an incomplete dataset, or some other error?

Comment: The resulting query returns an incomplete dataset.

Comment: I see that your query:

`SELECT * FROM database.view2 WHERE REPLACE(Id, char(9), '') = '2012 '`
returns nothing from your original post, but does:

`SELECT * FROM database.view2 WHERE REPLACE(Id, char(9), '') = '2012'` also return nothing? (there's no space after the 2012 in the latter)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

INNER JOIN view AS vw ON ltrim(rtrim(vw.[Id])) = ltrim(rtrim(vw2.[Id]))

Comment: INNER JOIN view AS vw ON  ltrim(rtrim(replace(vw.[Id],char(9), ''))) = ltrim(rtrim(replace(vw2.[Id], char(9), ''))

Comment: I don't think this is good practice since the query is running for 5 mins already and still no result wherein the original takes only about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the original question, but it may function as a work-around:

```
INNER JOIN view AS vw ON CONVERT(integer, vw.[Id]) = CONVERT(integer, vw2.[Id])
```

If all of the IDs are integer-like (as your '2012 ' example is).

Comment: Hi @Sturgus I only used 2012 as an example but the Id is a combination of String-Int that's why i'm using nvarchar. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Darn.  Back to the drawing board.